# I can't copy exact amount of whitespaces from a pdf file

Tags: pdf, ide, whitespace, copy-paste

For homework, I need to copy this template from pdf but I can't get exact amount of whitespaces from copy pasting. How can I solve that?

Code from pdf:

[image]

Code after copy-paste:

```
System.out.println("j\tK--A--F--V--Ş--V--F--A--K");
System.out.println(" \t| | | |\\ | /| | | |");
System.out.println("i\t-------------------------");
System.out.println(" \t| | | |/ | \\| | | |");
System.out.println("h\t---T-----------------T---");
System.out.println(" \t| | | | | | | | |");
System.out.println("g\tE-----E-----E-----E-----E");
System.out.println(" \t| | | | | | | | |");
System.out.println("f\t-------------------------");
System.out.println(" \t| |");
System.out.println("e\t-------------------------");
System.out.println(" \t| | | | | | | | |");
System.out.println("d\te-----e-----e-----e-----e");
System.out.println(" \t| | | | | | | | |");
System.out.println("c\t---t-----------------t---");
System.out.println(" \t| | | |/ | \\| | | |");
System.out.println("b\t-------------------------");
System.out.println(" \t| | | |\\ | /| | | |");
System.out.println("a\tk--a--f--v--ş--v--f--a--k");
System.out.println();
System.out.println(" \t1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9");
```

Comment: Try changing the font in the document you are pasting into to a fixed pitch font like Courier. That may not work though as there are no spaces in PDF. Only positions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pdftotext fixed width "-LAYOUT" extractor to inject the same amount of whitespace bars,
[image] However, it only takes a fast find and replace to correct in 15 seconds, thus faster than write a line of code and test it !

```
System.out.println("j\tK--A--F--V--Ş--V--F--A--K");
System.out.println(" \t|  |  |  |\\| /|  |  |  |");
System.out.println("i\t-------------------------");
System.out.println(" \t|  |  |  |/ |\\|  |  |  |");
System.out.println("h\t---T-----------------T---");
System.out.println(" \t|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |");
System.out.println("g\tE-----E-----E-----E-----E");
System.out.println(" \t|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |");
System.out.println("f\t-------------------------");
System.out.println(" \t|                       |");
System.out.println("e\t-------------------------");
System.out.println(" \t|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |");
System.out.println("d\te-----e-----e-----e-----e");
System.out.println(" \t|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |");
System.out.println("c\t---t-----------------t---");
System.out.println(" \t|  |  |  |/ |\\|  |  |  |");
System.out.println("b\t-------------------------");
System.out.println(" \t|  |  |  |\\| /|  |  |  |");
System.out.println("a\tk--a--f--v--ş--v--f--a--k");
System.out.println();
System.out.println(" \t1--2--3--4--5--6--7--8--9");
```

But you need to check if the spaces are correctly exported by the extractor as a Non-proportional "Typewriter" font such as historic Courier